# Expectation of GeometricBrownianMotionProcess

Tags: random, distributions, stochastic-calculus

I am trying to compute 
$$\mathbb E\left[\max\left(\frac{S_{1/2}+S_1}{2}-K,0\right)\right]$$
where $K=100$ and $S_t$ is a geometric brownian motion (with $S_0=100$, drift $r=0.05$ and volatility $\sigma=0.4$) which satisfies 
$$dS_t=rS_tdt+\sigma S_tdW_t \quad \text{for} \quad0\le t\le T=1$$

So I use

```
ClearAll["Global`*"]
r = 0.05;
sigma = 0.4;
S0 = 100;
NExpectation[Max[(S12 + S1)/2 - 100, 0],
  {S12, S1} \[Distributed] GeometricBrownianMotionProcess[r, sigma, S0][{1/2, 1}]]
```

which gives

```
0.754031
```

But according to my lecture notes the value should be much higher, in fact, it should be $\approx14$ (or $\approx 15$).

But what am I doing wrong? I suppose it might be due to the fact that $S_1$ and $S_{1/2}$ are not independent, but Mathematica probably assumes they are independent.

Comment: How did you compute `S1` and `S12`? Without that information, I don't see how to work with your problem.

Comment: I have not "computed" `S1` and `S12`, they follow the distribution of `GeometricBrownianMotionProcess[r, sigma, S0][{1/2, 1}]`. This is how the NExpectation-operator works, does it not?

Comment: Another approach is to use this: `NExpectation[
 Max[(S12 + S1)/2 - 100, 
  0], {S12 \[Distributed] 
   GeometricBrownianMotionProcess[r, sigma, S0][1/2], 
  S1 \[Distributed] GeometricBrownianMotionProcess[r, sigma, S0][1]}]` which gives 0.384216 (not 14 either).

Comment: You dont want `S1` and `S12` to be independent, so this last approach is not going to give the result. According to the documentation, `SliceDistribution[proc, {t1,..., tk}]`
represents the joint distribution of process states at times `t1<...<tk`. This can also be input as `proc[{t1,...,tk}]` as you did in your original post.

Comment: @m_goldberg S1 and S12 are just variables that follow the given distribution. They don't have values or definitions for them.

Comment: @Eckhard Thanks for the tip, but it does not appear to solve my problem since `SliceDistribution[GeometricBrownianMotionProcess[r, sigma, S0], {1/2, 1}]` and `GeometricBrownianMotionProcess[r, sigma, S0][{1/2, 1}]` are the same.

Comment: @Tom: indeed. It's interesting, `n = 10000;
Max[Total[#]/2 - 100, 0] & /@ 
  RandomVariate[GeometricBrownianMotionProcess[r, sigma, S0][{.5, 1}],
    n] // Mean` gives indeed roughly 14.

Comment: @Tom If I just generate random numbers and compute the mean, I get about 14.7... `NExpectation`'s value seems to be off by a factor of $1/r$. Coincidence? It doesn't hold if I change $r$ though... are your values for $S_0$ and $K$ valid for all $r$ or just for $r=0.05$?

Comment: @rm-rf Interesting observation, but as you said, it appears to be a fluke since e.g. if we have `S0=95, K=105, sigma=0.2, r=0.1` then the expectation should be $\approx 5$, but `NExpectation` gives 0.00004025 which is off by more than just $1/r$.

Comment: Something weird is going on in `Nintegrate` I believe. `pdf[s12_?NumericQ,s1_?NumericQ]:=PDF[GeometricBrownianMotionProcess[r,sigma,S0][{.5,1}],{s12,s1}]
NIntegrate[Max[(s12+s1)/2-100,0] pdf[s12,s1],{s12,0,1000},{s1,0,1000}]` gives about the right result of `14....`, but replacing the integration boundary `1000` by `Infinity` gives `0.754...`. Changing the order of integration gives yet another result.

Comment: `NExpectation[
 Max[(S12 + S1)/2 - 100, 0], {S1, S12} \[Distributed] 
  SliceDistribution[
   GeometricBrownianMotionProcess[r, sigma, S0], {1/2, 1}], 
 Method -> "MonteCarlo"]`

Comment: With `MinRecursion->3` the integrals are evaluated correctly. I don't know how to pass on that option to `NExpectation`.

Comment: Your code results in `14.8257` in version 10, guess something has been corrected.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
NExpectation[
 Max[(S12 + S1)/2 - 100, 0], {S1, S12} \[Distributed] 
  SliceDistribution[ GeometricBrownianMotionProcess[r, sigma, S0], {1/2, 1}], 
 Method -> "MonteCarlo"]
```

or

```
NExpectation[
 Max[(S12 + S1)/2 - 100, 0], {S1, S12} \[Distributed] 
  SliceDistribution[ GeometricBrownianMotionProcess[r, sigma, S0], {1/2, 1}], 
 Method -> {"NIntegrate", {MinRecursion -> 1, MaxRecursion -> 10}}]
```

Give 14.8153 and 14.8257 respectively...

Comment: Thanks for pointing out how to pass `Nintegrate` options to `NExpectation`.

Comment: @Eckhard: one of the few areas the *MMA* documentations blows is making clear the "passing options to underlying methods..." cases :-(

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for! Just one follow-up question: The value from the MonteCarlo-version obviously varies every time, but the NIntegrate-version remains the same. So I assume the latter one is more accurate, but is there any way of knowning how accurate 14.8257 actually is?

Comment: @Tom - you can pass accuracy/precision requirements via options, and check final accuracy/precision with the `Accuracy` and `Precision` functions. And yes, assuming proper evaluation of the integral, I suppose one could call it "more accurate" in the loose sense of the word (the mean of MC results would be be same). I'm sure experts in that question will chime in...